# Disk based HashMap

Tags: java, data-persistence

Does Java have (or is there a library available) that allows me to have a disk based HashMap?  It doesn't need to be atomic or anything, but it will be accessed via multiple threads and shouldn't crash if two are accessing the same element at the same time.

Anyone know of anything?

Comment: what is a "disk based (Hash)Map"?

Comment: The filesystem, perhaps?

Comment: @Progman 

Something like python's http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#module-shelve module is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either [properties files](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) or [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) might be what you're looking for. The [`java.util.Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) itself implements `java.util.Map` and provides methods to `load` from and `store` to a file. The Berkeley DB is often been recommended as a lightweight key-value pair datastore.

Comment: I think Properties will be perfect.  I don't know why I thought I had to complicate this, hah.

Comment: Properties is not threadsafe which you said you needed. Just imagine two threads writing the file to disk at the same time.

You could program around that or take a look at http://ehcache.org/ which would also provide much better performance if needed.

Comment: Properties extends Hashtable, so it is thread-safe, only that concurrent reads are synchronized, so performance hurts.

Answer (score 33):

**MapDB**

MapDB provides concurrent TreeMap and HashMap backed by disk storage or off-heap-memory. It is a fast, scalable and easy to use embedded Java database engine. It is packed with features such as transactions, space efficient serialization, instance cache and transparent compression/encryption. It also has outstanding performance rivaled only by native embedded db engines.

http://www.mapdb.org/

**jdbm2**

Embedded Key Value Java database.

https://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/

Answer (score 12):

In `2018` the lightest persistent `key value` store is the [H2 Database with it's MVStore](http://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html):

> The MVStore is a persistent, log structured key-value store. It is
>   planned to be the next storage subsystem of H2, but it can also be
>   used directly within an application, without using JDBC or SQL.
>
> - MVStore stands for "multi-version store".
> - Each store contains a number of maps that can be accessed using the java.util.Map interface.
> - Both file-based persistence and in-memory operation are supported.
> - It is intended to be fast, simple to use, and small.
> - Concurrent read and write operations are supported.
> - Transactions are supported (including concurrent transactions and 2-phase commit).
> - The tool is very modular. It supports pluggable data types and serialization, pluggable storage (to a file, to off-heap memory), pluggable map implementations (B-tree, R-tree, concurrent B-tree currently), BLOB storage, and a file system abstraction to support encrypted files and zip files.

[h2-mvstore](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.h2database%20AND%20a:h2-mvstore) has no dependencies and version 1.4.200 is a single jar of [0.3 Mb](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2-mvstore/1.4.200/)

I also looked at:

- [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) (`13 meg` dependencies)
- [chronicle-map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) (`5.5 meg` dependencies - fast optionally distributed)
- [lmdbjava](https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava) (`2 meg` java dependencies + `lmdb` C library) - fastest implementation but not `thread safe` out of the box.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you need something close to a lightweight db. Have you looked at/considered [Java DB?](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javadb/) A light db with a single, indexed table would basically be a disk-based, thread-safe hash map.

Comment: I looked into exactly this at one point--actually going from the mindset of a hash map to a disk based hash map to a DB which is essentially a disk based hash map.  There were a few really good one that you can just include the jar and use it, and that was 5+ years ago.  There is a good discussion of databases here: http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/software-development/TCH_SFT/1207-3692603

Comment: I'm actually already use sqlite for this problem, but really all I need is just a threadsafe String key/value store.

Answer (score 7):

[JDBM2](http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/) is exactly what you are asking. It provides a HashMap backed up by disk storage (among other maps). Its fast, thread-safe and the API is really simple.

Comment: I had the same problem and JDBM2 was perfect for solving it. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 6):

[**Chronicle Map**](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) implements `ConcurrentMap` and persists data to disk via mapping it's memory to a file.

Chronicle Map is conceptually very similar to MapDB (provides similar builder API and `Map` interface), but Chronicle Map is [times faster](http://jetbrains.github.io/xodus/#benchmarks) than MapDB and has much better concurrency (Chronicle Map uses highly striped multi-level spin locks).

Answer (score 5):

[Project Voldemort](http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/) is also a really fast/scalable/replication "Hashmap". It is used at LinkedIn an performance is also pretty good:

A quote from their site:

> Here is the throughput we see from a
>   single multithreaded client talking to
>   a single server where the "hot" data
>   set is in memory under artificially
>   heavy load in our performance lab:
>
> Reads: 19,384 req/sec
>    Writes: 16,559 req/sec

Answer (score 2):

So the year is now 2016. And if anyone's looking to tackle this problem, I found out that the low level environments API in [Xodus](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus) from JetBrains works for this same purpose, using their `computeInTransaction` store lambdas.

Granted, it's not as slick as having a pure `Map` instance, but it worked for my use case.

Another recent option is to use [H2's `MVStore` storage engine](http://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html) which does the same thing, but I think it's more tailored towards the database itself.

Cheers!