# how to persiste data without calling any method?

Tags: types, data-storage, data-persistence

Today on a class my teacher stated sth I had not heard before. she talked about some kind of data types which hold the data even after you close the program so that after you run the code again u can access the data u stored on the last run(without calling any method to save it on any kind of database). does anyone know sth like that?

Comment: Very, very vague. Note that data persisting doesn't help without finding/identifying it.

Comment: @greybeard thats the point. what i grasped was that it doesnt need a call to any persisting method. It is a vague topic to me, thats why my question seems vague too

Comment: On the upside, you succeeded in tagging [tag:data-persistence]. Keywords like [orthogonal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)#Orthogonal_or_transparent_persistence) and [transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdata-persistence%5D+transparent) lead to information like [2018 lightweight persistent key-value stores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50964567). Some reading done, you should be able to improve on this question's title and body (the preferred tone being *getting help from a busy co-worker*, not *wise-cracking with a bored class mate*: drop `u`&co).